# Saving data in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

We have a lot of Controller `ActionResult`s like this in our MVC project. The controllers get really cluttered up. This is a simple example, but we have much more complex `ActionResult`s.

This controller accepts a model, and if the primary key is `Guid.Empty`, handles it as an `Add`/`Create`. Otherwise it handles it as an edit.

When we started this project we were told that we don't need a Data Layer, since Entity Framework handles a lot of things, but I'm thinking it may be better to have one to handle some of these.

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> _projectedit(ProjectCreate model)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        Project project = null;

        if (model.ProjectId == Guid.Empty)
        {
            project = new Project()
            {
                ProjectTypeId = model.ProjectTypeId,
                ProjectTemplateId = model.ProjectTemplateId,
                Title = model.Title,
                Subtitle = model.Subtitle,
                CoverImage = model.CoverImage,
                Volume = model.Volume,
                Issue = model.Issue,
                Edition = model.Edition,
                CopyrightYear = model.CopyrightYear,
                WordCount = model.WordCount,
                ProjectDescription = model.ProjectDescription,
                CreatedById = SessionUser.ProfileId,
                IsActive = true
            };
            db.Project.Add(project);
        }
        else
        {
            project = db.Project.Find(model.ProjectId);
            project.ProjectTypeId = model.ProjectTypeId;
            project.ProjectTemplateId = model.ProjectTemplateId;
            project.Title = model.Title;
            project.Subtitle = model.Subtitle;
            project.CoverImage = model.CoverImage;
            project.Volume = model.Volume;
            project.Issue = model.Issue;
            project.Edition = model.Edition;
            project.CopyrightYear = model.CopyrightYear;
            project.WordCount = model.WordCount;
            project.ProjectDescription = model.ProjectDescription;
        }

        db.SaveChanges();

        var success = new StringBuilder();

        success.Append("<p>");
        success.Append(Tools.Format.Title(model.Title, model.Subtitle));
        success.Append(" has been created and can be accessed from the <a href=\"/project/\">Projects</a> page");
        success.Append(".</p>");
        success.Append("<p><a href=\"/\">Return to home page</a>.");

        AddMessage(success.ToString());

        return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Project", new { id = project.ProjectId });
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

Comment: Btw, this code contains pieces from more than one developer, so this will help our whole team. Thank you.

Comment: It maybe useful to use something like `AutoMapper` to assign properties so reduce code lines.

Answer (score 6):

1. Extract that logic into a data layer. *Minimally*, extract a private `Upsert` method.
2. Create an extension method for cloning the properties from one of your models to another.
3. Stop this nonsense.

> ```
> success.Append("<p>");
> success.Append(Tools.Format.Title(model.Title, model.Subtitle));
> success.Append(" has been created and can be accessed from the <a href=\"/project/\">Projects</a> page");
> success.Append(".</p>");
> success.Append("<p><a href=\"/\">Return to home page</a>.");
>
> AddMessage(success.ToString());
> ```

The view logic belongs in the view. Create a partial view that gets conditionally rendered. (Toggled on/off)

Comment: I just noticed your note about being told you didn't need a data layer because you're using entity framework. I don't know where people ever got that idea, but it's common and wrong in my opinion.

Comment: RubberDuck, are there any samples out there showing a good design pattern for the data layer? We have our Models/Context in it's own project. ViewModels are in the Web project.

Answer (score 4):

> ```
> public virtual async Task<ActionResult> _projectedit(ProjectCreate model)
> ```

- Based on the [Task-based Asynchronous Pattern (TAP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh873175.aspx) one should add the postfix `Async` to the methodname for `async` methods.
- Based on the [NET naming guidelines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing. Having an underscore prefixed methodname is really unusual. Underscore prefixing is tolerable for `private` class level variables but thats it.
- Based on the same naming guideline method names should be made out of verbs or verb phrases so if you want to keep `edit` and `project` in that name it should be `EditProject`.
- This method is either adding or updating a `Project` so a name which is reflecting this would be better like `AddOrUpdateProject`.
- Extracting the adding and updating to separate methods will reduce the length of that method and makes it more readable.
- The message you are building is lying if a `Project` is edited, because it states " has been created". Best way to do the messagebuilding is, if you want/have to go this way, to extract this to a separate method passing the `ProjectCreate model` as an argument.
- By reverting the condition `if (ModelState.IsValid)` you could (and should) return early which shaves off one level of indentation which results in less horizontal spacing hence increasing readability.
- A method named `AddMessage` doesn't tell where the message is added to which will reduce the ability of **Sam the maintainer** to graps the purpose at first glance.
- Having the [`async`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh156513.aspx) keyword without having an `await` will result in the method running synchronously and a compiler warning will be returned.

Implementing some of this points will lead to

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public virtual async Task<ActionResult> AddOrUpdateProjectAsync(ProjectCreate model)
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return View(model);
    }

    Guid projectId = Guid.Empty;   
    if (model.ProjectId == Guid.Empty)
    {  
        projectId = AddProject(model);
    }
    else
    {
        projectId = UpdateProject(model);
    }  

    db.SaveChanges();

    AddMessage(model);

    return RedirectToAction("Edit", "Project", new { id = projectId });

}
```

Comment: Excellent, thank you. One question, AddProject and UpdateProject. I understand those methods are where a bunch of logic get put. But where should I put those? Should I have a DataLayer for MVC projects?

Comment: This methods can be private ones which could live in the same class as the former one.